# Python: NLTK: sentiment analysis

Tags: python, twitter, nltk, sentiment-analysis

I have a huge block of code, I didn't want to bother you with in the first place. I tried figuring out what's going wrong for over a week now and I contacted several external sources (without any response), and at the moment I'm just wondering: maybe the problem is my training set?

For my thesis I need to classify a whole bunch of tweets as pos/neg/neutral. The code I wrote works OK on test datasets I make up myself (e.g. consisting out of 15 training sentences: 5 pos, 5 neg and 5 neutral; 6 test sentences: 2 pos, 2 neg, 2 neutral - only 1 test sentence gets misclassified).

Once I start running the code on the manually classified training set (1629 pos, 1411 neutral tweets and only 690 neg) and 900 test tweets, things start going wrong. Of the 900 test tweets, the HUGE majority gets classified as pos (between 700 and 800), while there's only a minority of neg and neutral tweets.

Would somebody please be so kind as to check my code and help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? I'd be really grateful. If you need any more information, I'd be happy to provide it.

```
import re, math, collections, itertools
import nltk
import nltk.classify.util, nltk.metrics
import csv
from nltk.classify import NaiveBayesClassifier
from nltk.metrics import BigramAssocMeasures
from nltk.probability import FreqDist, ConditionalFreqDist  
from nltk.util import ngrams
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from nltk.stem.porter import *
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer


stemmer = SnowballStemmer("english", ignore_stopwords = True)
pos = []
neg = []
neutral = []
with open('C:\\...pos.csv', 'r', encoding = "utf8") as f:  #open positive training set
    reader = csv.reader(f) 
    for row in reader:
        pos.extend(row)

with open('C:\\ ...neg.csv', 'r', encoding = "utf8") as f: #open negative training set
    reader = csv.reader(f) 
    for row in reader:
        neg.extend(row)

with open('C:\\...neutral.csv', 'r', encoding = "utf8") as f: #open neutral training set
    reader = csv.reader(f) 
    for row in reader:
        neutral.extend(row)


def uni(doc):
    x = []
    y = []
    for tweet in doc:
        x.append(word_tokenize(tweet))
    for element in x:
        for word in element:
            if len(word)>2:
                word = word.lower()
                word = stemmer.stem(word)
                y.append(word)
    return y

def word_feats_uni(doc):
     return dict([(word, True) for word in uni(doc)])

def tokenizer_ngrams(document):
    all_tokens = []
    filtered_tokens = []
    for (sentence) in document:
        all_tokens.append(word_tokenize(sentence))
    return all_tokens

def get_bi (document):
    x = tokenizer_ngrams(document)
    c = []
    for sentence in x:
        c.extend([bigram for bigram in nltk.bigrams(sentence)])
    return c

def get_tri(document):
    x = tokenizer_ngrams(document)
    c = []
    for sentence in x:
        c.extend([bigram for bigram in nltk.bigrams(sentence)])
    return c


def word_feats_bi(doc): 
    return dict([(word, True) for word in get_bi(doc)])

def word_feats_tri(doc):
    return dict([(word, True) for word in get_tri(doc)])

def word_feats_test(doc):
    feats_test = {}
    feats_test.update(word_feats_uni(doc))
    feats_test.update(word_feats_bi(doc))
    feats_test.update(word_feats_tri(doc))
    return feats_test


pos_feats = [(word_feats_uni(pos),'1')] + [(word_feats_bi(pos),'1')] + [(word_feats_tri(pos),'1')]

neg_feats = [(word_feats_uni(neg),'-1')] + [(word_feats_bi(neg),'-1')] + [(word_feats_tri(neg),'-1')]

neutral_feats = [(word_feats_uni(neutral),'0')] + [(word_feats_bi(neutral),'0')] + [(word_feats_tri(neutral),'0')]

trainfeats = pos_feats + neg_feats + neutral_feats
random.shuffle(trainfeats)
classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(trainfeats)

testtweets = []
with open('C:\\ ... testtweets.csv', 'r', encoding = "utf8") as f: #open testset
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ';') 
    for row in reader:
        testtweets.extend([row])



date = []
word = []
y = []

def classification(date,sentence): #doc = sentencelist
    i = 0
    for tweet in sentence:
        sent = classifier.classify(word_feats_test([tweet]))
        y.extend([(date[i],tweet,sent)])
        i = i + 1

def result(doc):
    i = 0
    while i in range(0,len(doc) -1):
        date.append(doc[i][0])
        word.append(doc[i][1])
        i = i + 1
    classification(date,word)

    result(testtweets) 

with open('C:\\...write.csv', 'w') as fp: #write classified test set to file
    a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
    a.writerows(y)
```

Comment: It looks like your training set is skewed. So the classifier hasn't fitted to the dominated set(negative tweets). There's many methods to cope with skewed data...

Comment: have you discovered your problem ? Consider posting as an answer :)